# trying to use sum and mean function togather both takes array as argument

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call a function inside another , i have made  two function one is sum that with add the elements of an array and another function will use this sum to calculate mean

```
function sum(array) {
  value = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    value = value + array[i]
    return value
  }
}
```

here i am trying to use sum function

```
function mean(array) {
  let total = sum(array);

  final = total / array.length
  return final
}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stack overflow. Could you please elaborate a bit more on your question? What exactly is the problem you're encountering when you run this code?

Comment: what are you trying to do here? you need both functions inside a 3rd function?

Comment: `return value` shouldn't be inside the loop. You're returning after adding the first array element, not the entire array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're encountering is due to a misplaced curly brace. Notice how in your sum function you have a return statement *inside* of the for loop. This causes the function to immediately exit without the for loop being completed. As it stands right now, this is how your code is working:

```
function sum(array) { // <-- Begin function
  var value = 0; // <-- Set "value" to 0
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // <-- Begin for loop for all elements in array
    value = value + array[i] // <-- Add to "value" the number stored in array[i]
    return value // <-- Stop! return "value" and exit the function ---
  }                                                               // |
}                                                                 // |
  // < -- We're now here, outside of the function. ------------------^
```

The solution to your problem is by putting the return statement *outside* of the for loop, since any return statement causes a function to immediately exit. The fixed code would look like this:

```
function sum(array) {  // <-- Begin function
  var value = 0; // <-- Set "value" to 0
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // <-- Begin for loop for all elements in array
    value = value + array[i] // <-- Add to "value" the data stored in array[i]
  }
  // Now the for loop has successfully finished.
  return value // <-- Stop! return "value" and exit the function -----
                                                                  // |
}                                                                 // |
  // < -- We're now here, outside of the function. ------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line, using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to determine the sum.

```js
const mean = arr => arr.reduce( (acc, val) => acc + val, 0) / arr.length;
console.log(mean([1,2,3,4,5]));
```